# Async method cannot return void when using await Task.Run

Tags: c#

My code looks like this:

```
private ICommand aBtnCmd;
private ICommand resetBtnCmd;

public ICommand ABtnCmd => aBtnCmd ?? (aBtnCmd = new Command(() => phrasesFrame.Btn((int)Settings.aBtn, 1)));
public ICommand ResetBtnCmd => resetBtnCmd ?? (resetBtnCmd = new Command(async () => await phrasesFrame.RBtn()));
```

with methods:

```
async public Task Btn(int pts, int col)
{
    Change.points = true;
    await Task.Run(() => App.DB.IncrementPoints(Settings.cfs, phrase, pts, col));
}

async public Task RBtn()
{
    await Messages.ResetButtonClicked();
}
```

Can someone give me advice as to how I can return from these methods?

The reason I am asking this is because when I hover over the async word here:

`new Command(async`

then the IDE gives a message saying:

`Asynchronous method '<anonymous' should not return void`

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to run these methods asynchronously, do they take a long time?

Comment: Do you have an actual error or is this just about a Warning?  Your 2nd lambda is an `async void` but that is Ok here.

Answer (score 0):

You can return something using the generic version of Task,

```
Task<T>
```

where T is the type of the object you want to return.

Your methods will look like this:

```
    public async Task<T> GetSomeValue()
    { 
        //Your function body to return an object of type T.
    }
```

Comment: Given these examples what would you suggest I return?

Comment: What is returned from your call to Task.Run(). You can use also here the generic version of the function to specify the type of the object your actual method is returning